# Modifing a list in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, request

How can I delete "//" from a list?

[image]

Comment: Try the `lstrip` function.

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to post code pictures, please include the code as text instead :)

Comment: I got. Work correctly. Tkhs!

Comment: Please paste the code, not image.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before by [101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470749/101), isn't a best practice post code in a image.

Please, update your question with the source code, it helps others to answer your question.

Now, related to your question, you can try this:

```py
urls = [
    '//somewebsite.com/foo/bar',
    '//anotherwebsite.com.br/page/2',
    'websitewhithoutslashs.com.br'
]

for url in urls:
    url_without_slash = url.removeprefix('//')
    print(url_without_slash)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to skip the first 2 characters in the string, you can try

```
print(i['src'][2:])
```

or

```
print(i['src'].lstrip('/'))
```

I notice you're trying to do something with your code. Do you mean this?

```
links = []

for i in elemento:
    links.append(i['src'][2:])

dez_primeiros = links[:10]
print(dez_primeiros)
```